# NSUserDefaults erased due to memory crash?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, nsuserdefaults

I have a situation, where my IOS app crashes due to low memory.  I notice that during such crashes, my UserDefault values are also erased.  Anyone had any similar experience? Or are they (memory crash and user defaults erase) un-related in my case?  (Do I need to look out for other reasons for erasing the User defaults?)

Thanks for your help

Edit: The issue was somewhere else.  Memory crash does not erase user defaults, once you synchronize.

Comment: They shouldn't be erased. Are you sure you have synchronized them before the app is killed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you haven't written them to disk regularily:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Thanks H2CO3.  You are correct. After synchronization call the user defaults do not get erased.  I had created a function to delete the user default values.  That method was getting called which I did not notice.  Thank you.

Comment: No prolem, I'm glad I could help you.